# The Search parameter does not work with Outlook restapi

Tags: php, rest, oauth-2.0, outlook-restapi

I've used the basic example/tutorial described in "https://github.com/jasonjoh/php-tutorial" and tried to add the "$search" parameter in the getMessages() function

```
    $getMessagesParameters = array (
        // Message Search Conditions
        "\$search" => 'subject:"pizza"',
        // Only return Subject, ReceivedDateTime, and From fields
        "\$select" => "Subject,Body",
        // Return at most 10 results
        "\$top" => "10"
    );
    $getMessagesUrl = self::$outlookApiUrl."/Me/Messages?".http_build_query($getMessagesParameters);
    $response = $this->makeApiCall($access_token, $user_email, "GET", $getMessagesUrl);
```

the request returns error 400

wonder what might be the correct syntax

I've referred the following links

https://msdn.microsoft.com/office/office365/api/complex-types-for-mail-contacts-calendar#UseODataqueryparametersSearchrequests

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc513841%28v=office.12%29.aspx

https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Learn-to-narrow-your-search-criteria-for-better-searches-in-Outlook-d824d1e9-a255-4c8a-8553-276fb895a8da

If someone have a better idea to search through the mails, please suggest...

Comment: Which version of the api are you using? Is it possible that you show the final request url (you can grab it via fiddler or your browser debugger - network section) ?

Comment: @BenoitPatra we can't use the browser debugger to capture the url... the request is made from the server... you could get the idea anyhow... the code uses `http_build_query()` and `$outlookApiUrl="https://outlook.office.com/api/v2.0"` . The result url will look something similar to `https://outlook.office.com/api/v2.0/Me/Messages?$search=subject:"pizza"&$select=Subject,Body&$orderby=ReceivedDateTime DESC&$top=10` and special characters might be url encoded... the point is when I remove the `$search` parameter, no error is returned

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've figured out the exact issue...

The Problem is not with the search parameter specifications / server REST Endpoints...

But the problem is with how we send the query params to the server...

We should not url encode the data.

but we need to replace the spaces with `+` in the result url

This is the solution I've come up with...

```
    $search_AQS = '"Subject:(pizza+OR+hamburger+OR+tacos)+AND+subject:(NOT+beef+NOT+pork)"';
    $getMessagesParameters = array (
        "\$search" => $search_AQS,
        "\$select" => "Subject,Body",
        "\$top" => "10"
    );
    $tmp_uripiece = http_build_query($getMessagesParameters);
    $tmp_uripiece = urldecode($tmp_uripiece);
    $getMessagesUrl = self::$outlookApiUrl.'/Me/Messages?'.$tmp_uripiece;
    $response = $this->makeApiCall($access_token, $user_email, "GET", $getMessagesUrl);
```

Yay! microsoft also supports search feature in their endpoints... but they should've documented with more examples...

Everybody thanks for your support...

Answer (score 0):

You can not use orderby in search results.
see https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/office365/api/complex-types-for-mail-contacts-calendar#UseODataqueryparametersSearchrequests
$search=subject:"pizza" should be $search=subject:pizza. But that is not working also.
I use $search=pizza and that works (without orderby)

Comment: Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.

Comment: @max, Sorry for the mistake, I've removed the `$orderby` from the parameters... But the problem is as you say, when I include the operator `:` in the search query, `$search=subject:pizza` I get a http 400 error... Is it from `curl()` or from the Outlook REST API Server Endpoint result? I'm not sure...